How to dissolve a powdered drug once it has been mixed with water
For a biological experiment I have acquired $\pu{10 mg}$ of CHIR 99021 (laduviglusib). In order to obtain a $\pu{10 mM}$ stock solution, I had to dissolve the powder in $\pu{2.15 mL}$ of dimethyl sulfoxide (DMSO). Unfortunately, I tried to dissolve the powder in distilled water.
That powder is said to be insoluble in water. In order to obtain again the powder, I tried to centrifuge the solution $(\pu{1500 rpm}, \ \pu{20 min})$, hoping that the powder would precipitate (sedimented), but nothing happened.
I would like to know how to dissolve that solution: I am thinking to put another $\pu{2.15 mL}$ of DMSO in the water solution in order to have a stock solution of $\pu{5 mM}$ (which would be fine for me).
What would you suggest? Thank you very much.

please do not capitalized the chemical names unless they are in the front of the sentences.

Since you are in a bioanalytical lab (I assumed), you can freeze-dried the sample to evaporate water before adding $\pu{2.15 mL}$ DMSO to the powder (hope vacuum didn't take away the fine powder).

@MathewMahindaratne Thank you very much for your kind reply. Would you suggest adding DMSO in water, obtaining a more diluted solution? Would it work in that way, from a chemical point of wiew? Thank you!

Laduviglusib might dissolve in 1:1 DMSO/water.  But there is a risk it might not because this is the reverse of usual procedure. Normally, we dissolve drugs in DMSO and then add water to dilute it.
